# Index error when using betfairlightweight

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to the site and fairly new to Python, so please excuse me if I've missed something obvious with the error I'm getting. 
I have started experimenting with betfairlightweight, experimenting with parsing some data from the betfair API and adding it to a dataframe. The script I have created works occasionally, but usually produces "IndexError: list index out of range".

The full error is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/leonf/PycharmProjects/betfair_historic/test 1.py", line 120, in <module>
    runners_df = process_runner_books(market_book.runners)
  File "C:/Users/leonf/PycharmProjects/betfair_historic/test 1.py", line 23, in process_runner_books
    in runner_books]
  File "C:/Users/leonf/PycharmProjects/betfair_historic/test 1.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
    for runner_book
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The error suggests that I am trying to access an item in a list that doesn't exist, and I believe the error is occurring in the process_runner_books function (this is actually sample code I took from the betfair developer website, rather than my own code).
I discovered that sometimes the data returned by the API is incomplete and will result in an empty list. At this point I was rather pleased with myself at having found the issue so set about writing some code to ignore empty lists:

```
def isEmpty(a):
    return all([isEmpty(b) for b in a]) if isinstance(a, list) else False
```

then inserting the following lines at the start of the process_runner_books function:

```
if isEmpty(runner_book.ex.available_to_back) ==False:
```

My reasoning being that if the list isn't empty the rest of the function should run, if it is empty the function does nothing.

This didn't work and produced the same error.

This is the function in which I believe the error is occuring (apologies for the length but I'm not sure it makes sense if I truncate it):

```
def process_runner_books(runner_books):
    best_back_prices = [runner_book.ex.available_to_back[0].price
                        if runner_book.ex.available_to_back[0].price
                        else 1.01
                        for runner_book
                        in runner_books]
    best_back_sizes = [runner_book.ex.available_to_back[0].size
                       if runner_book.ex.available_to_back[0].size
                       else 1.01
                       for runner_book
                       in runner_books]

    best_lay_prices = [runner_book.ex.available_to_lay[0].price
                       if runner_book.ex.available_to_lay[0].price
                       else 1000.0
                       for runner_book
                       in runner_books]
    best_lay_sizes = [runner_book.ex.available_to_lay[0].size
                      if runner_book.ex.available_to_lay[0].size
                      else 1.01
                      for runner_book
                      in runner_books]

    selection_ids = [runner_book.selection_id for runner_book in runner_books]
    last_prices_traded = [runner_book.last_price_traded for runner_book in runner_books]
    total_matched = [runner_book.total_matched for runner_book in runner_books]
    statuses = [runner_book.status for runner_book in runner_books]
    scratching_datetimes = [runner_book.removal_date for runner_book in runner_books]
    adjustment_factors = [runner_book.adjustment_factor for runner_book in runner_books]

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Selection ID': selection_ids,
        'Best Back Price': best_back_prices,
        'Best Back Size': best_back_sizes,
        'Best Lay Price': best_lay_prices,
        'Best Lay Size': best_lay_sizes,
        'Last Price Traded': last_prices_traded,
        'Total Matched': total_matched,
        'Status': statuses,
        'Removal Date': scratching_datetimes,
        'Adjustment Factor': adjustment_factors
    })
    return df
```

and this is the code that uses the function above:

```
market_IDs = []
for market_catalogue in market_catalogues:
    market_IDs = market_IDs + [market_catalogue.market_id]
GB_runners_df = pd.DataFrame()  # create an empty dataframe to append other dfs to
# market book request
for market in market_IDs:
    # Create a price filter. Get all traded and offer data
    price_filter = filters.price_projection(
        price_data=['EX_BEST_OFFERS']
    )
    market_books = trading.betting.list_market_book(
        market_ids=[market],
        price_projection=price_filter
    )
    # append the new market book runners to the final dataframe
    market_book = market_books[0]
    runners_df = process_runner_books(market_book.runners)
    runners_df['Event_ID'] = market
    GB_runners_df = GB_runners_df.append(runners_df, ignore_index=True)
```

I expect to get a dataframe (GB_runners_df) which has information about the runners, and an additional column with the event ID. I do get this result occassionally, but I usually get the error described above.
A sample of what it should look like (from one of the times there wasn't an error) -

```
    Selection ID  Best Back Price  ...  Adjustment Factor     Event_ID
0          15067             3.15  ...             32.258  1.156783632
1       11985860             4.60  ...             20.281  1.156783632
2       10308561             6.40  ...             15.701  1.156783632
3       15786072             7.00  ...             14.316  1.156783632
4       11889221            11.00  ...              9.271  1.156783632
5          19453            23.00  ...              4.233  1.156783632
6        6363328            38.00  ...              2.318  1.156783632
7        7364735            46.00  ...              1.622  1.156783632
8       11487425             3.80  ...             25.974  1.156783637
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by a runner not having any prices, you need to update the prices/sizes code, for example:

```
best_back_prices = [runner_book.ex.available_to_back[0].price
                    if runner_book.ex.available_to_back
                    else 1.01
                    for runner_book
                    in runner_books]
```

(I was alerted to the question by the slack group, feel free to join as we will be able to answer your questions a lot quicker)

https://github.com/liampauling/betfair

Comment: great! thanks for responding, I've tried your suggestion and it fixed the issue. Thanks also for the invite to the slack group, I'll take a look.